# Calculate months difference Info-path form SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath, datepicker

I have two date fields(start date and end date) in infopath form and a text field. In this text field the difference in months needs to be calculated.

Condition :

```
if the difference is 4 months and 20(>15) days then it 5 months should be calculated in text field
                     4 months and 4 days then it should be 4 months
                     same month less than 15 days then 0 month 
                     same month more than 15 days then 1 month
```